# How to record live streaming audio | iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am working on a radio app. I am recording that live audio stream through AVAudioQueue but problem is it records outer noise as well. I want a way to remove that outer noise. I just want to record that stream only.
Please help me. I am stuck on it.

Comment: Are you saying that audio from the microphone is unintentionally getting in to your recording?

Comment: yes, because AudioQueue use mic as input source due to which out noises came to recording. I want a way to just record audio live stream.

Comment: I have used SpeakHere Example of apple to do this recording stuff but the problem is to skip outer noises coming from mic. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use lowpass/highpass filters to filter the data you get. You can take a look at [AccelerometerGraph](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code from Apple, to see how they implement these filters.
You you adjust filters properly you probably can get rid of some noise.

Comment: I have seen this code(AccelerometerGraph) but this is different thing for which I am looking is fine recording of live stream.

Comment: @user1048238 I know it's different, it works with accelerometer and draws a graph from it's data. But it also has 2 good classes named LowpassFilter and HighpassFilter which you can also use to filter your audio data to avoid noise.

Comment: OK, I will test it but do you know any good way of recording live audio stream?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. I have always used AudioQueue and for me it worked perfectly. It records audio with the same quality the AVAudioRecorder does if you set the same settings. If you are OK with the audio for example Voice Memos records, then AudioQueue is a good choice. The noise you get may be because you set it wrong, i had this behavior once.  It really shouldn't produce any bad noise.

Comment: The outer noise means audio queue takes input from mic and if mic open then outer voices are also captured in capturing of audio stream. My concern is to just capture the audio stream. Please help me in this regard.